# C++ string array and bools

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm currently trying to make a little recipe app. I have made a `string` array with 10 strings and 10 bools. For example, when I type Cinnemon I want to make the `_Cinnemon` true. How do I do that?

Also, is this written correctly, or could I make it better? I'm quite new to programming.

Lastly, how can I fix it so it doesn't have anything to say whether it's small letters or big?

Here's the code:

```
std::cout << "Welcome, type your ingredients " << std::endl;
std::string ingredients[10]{"Cinnemon", "Milk", "Eggs", "Butter", "Tomatoes", "Salt", "Backing Soda", "Suggar", "Chicken", "Honny"};
bool _cinnemon, _milk, _eggs, _butter, _tomatoes, _salt, _backingSoda, _Suggar, _chicken, _honny;
std::string ingredient;
int i = -1;
while (i = -1) {
    std::cin >> ingredient;
    i++;
    while (i < 9)
    {
        if (ingredient == ingredients[i]){
            std::cout << "Type another if you have any more igredients else type Exit" << std::endl;
            i++;
        } if (ingredient == "Exit" || "exit"){
            return 0;
        } else{
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are learning, so I'll avoid advanced datastructures such as maps and sets, which would be used for a real life application.

My proposed solution just uses an array of boolean.  For every indegrients which string is found, I set the boolean flag at the same index.  Here is how it works:

```
std::cout << "Welcome, type your ingredients " << std::endl;
const size_t maxind = 10;  // avoid hard coded size !  
std::string ingredients[maxind]{"Cinnemon", "Milk", "Eggs", "Butter", "Tomatoes", "Salt", "Backing Soda", "Suggar", "Chicken", "Honny"};
bool hasindegrient[maxind]{}; // make a table to know which one is present
std::string ingredient;
bool stopit = false;  // exit requested ? 
while (! stopit) {
    std::cin >> ingredient;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<maxind; i++) 
        if (ingredient == ingredients[i]){
            hasindegrient[i] = true; // <================ set flag of indegrient
            break;
        }
    if (i==maxind) { // here we didn't find it ! 
        if (ingredient == "Exit" || ingredient == "exit")
            stopit = true;
        else  
            std::cout << "Indegrient not found !" << std::endl;
    if (!stopit)
        std::cout << "Type another if you have any more igredients else type Exit" << std::endl;
    }
} 
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)  // display the indegrient list
    if (hasindegrient[i])
        cout << ingredients[i]<< " "; 
cout << endl;
```

With this approach, each boolean is anonymous: each `hasindegrient[i]` is either true or false, but has no name.  So on its own it doesn't mean anything. But in this programme, if `hasindegrient[i]` is true, it means that `indegrients[i]` is in the receipe.

If you want to add some logic where your code interprets the content of the receipe, you could add at the begin an enum that gives a logical name to each index:

```
enum {IDG_Cinnemon, IDG_Milk, IDG_Eggs, IDG_Butter, IDG_Tomatoes, IDG_Salt, IDG_Backing_Soda, IDG_Suggar, IDG_Chicken, IDG_Honny };
```

You can understand each element of this enumeration as a constant. As you see, I've followed the same order than in the table of strings. This allows then the writing of code such as:

```
if (hasindegrient[IDG_Butter]) {
    std::cout << "Take care of your cholesterol" << std::endl;
}
```

**Important remarks:**

I think you should know some problems of your original code:

- `while (i = -1)` will loop forever, whatever the value of i is. `=` is the assignement operator (i.e. -1 is copied to i and the value of i is evaluated in  condition).  This is the most common errors when starting with C/C++:  you certainly meant `while (i==-1)`  which is a comparison.
- `ingredient == "Exit" || "exit"` is a valid syntax.  But this condition is always true.  It does in no way mean "indegrient is either Exit or exit" .  For this you'd write `ingredient == "Exit" || ingredient =="exit"`
- your loop structure will not succeed in the search. Especially if the entering of the indegrients doesn't follow the predefined list...

Comment: How do I write a bool array? cant find anything online

Comment: It's `bool myarray[size];`  in the code above (4th line) I've added `{}` to initialise all the elements to false.

Comment: so I shouldnt write anything more there? I wrote {"_cinnemon"} but it didnt work

Comment: No nothing more !  If you have individual boolean variables like in your original code, each one shall have its own name. But if you have an array, the index is sufficient.  So here `indegrients[0]` is a string of value "Cinnamon", and `hasindegrient[0]` is a boolean without name that is either true of false.  On its own it doesn't mean anything.  But in your programme, you know that if `hasindegrient[0]` is true, it means that `indegrients[0]` is in the reciepe.

Comment: Is it possible to make so it isnt keysencitive without typing everything again with small letters?

Comment: @PetterS I've added a litttle explanation/example if you want to programmatically access tou your boolean by names.

Comment: @PetterS for case insensitivity, the easiest approach would be to do the comparison by converting both sides to lowercase.   The answer of Ra1nWarden shows how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to map your hard-coded strings into booleans. So you can change them easily.

```
map<string, bool> m;
m["blah"] = false; // Initialize to false
// Later, you can change it by
m["blah"] = true;
// To look up a value, simply do
if(m.count("blah") && m["blah"]) {
  // "blah" is true and do whatever you want to do here
}
```

As for string comparison ignoring the case, you can write your own function to do that, for example

```
#include <cctype>  // This is where tolower() is defined
bool stringCmpIgnoreCase(string a, string b) {
  if(a.length() != b.length())
    return false;
  for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    if(tolower(a[i]) != tolower(b[i]))
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `if(m["blah"])` This will not do what you expect, it will insert an element into the map.

Comment: I like your solution ! Especially if considering adding quantities of your indegreints.  Nevertheless instead of a `map<string, bool>` I'd use a simple `set<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for this task. For example you could use a bool array and an enumeration with names of ingredients that would be used as indices of the array.

You could use `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>`

You could use an array of pairs `std::pair<std::string, bool>.`

Also you can use std::map.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::map<std::string, bool> ingredients =
    {
        { "Cinnemon", false }, { "Milk", false }, { "Eggs",false },
        { "Butter", false }, { "Tomatoes", false }, { "Salt", false },
        { "Backing Soda", false }, { "Suggar", false }, { "Chicken", false },
        { "Honny", false }
    };

    std::cout << "Welcome, type your ingredients\n" << std::endl;

    std::string ingredient;
    bool selected = false;

    while ( std::getline(std::cin, ingredient ) )
    {
        if ( ingredient == "Exit" | ingredient == "exit" ) break;

        if ( selected = ( ingredients.count( ingredient ) != 0 ) )
        {
            ingredients[ingredient] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid ingredient." << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Type another if you have any more igredients else type Exit" << std::endl;
    }

    if ( selected )
    {
        std::cout << "You selected ingredients:"  << std::endl;
        for ( const auto &p : ingredients )
        {
            if ( p.second ) std::cout << p.first << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that you have to use function `std::getline` instead of `operator >>` because some ingredient names consist from several words.

Also you should make case insensitive search.